# Moving my mercurial repository to the central server, make mine a clone

Tags: mercurial

Let's say my development team has a central server where we all clone our repos from, and commit/push back to it.

Now let's say I create a new repo on my desktop, hg init, commit.  How can I make this repo on my desktop become the "parent" repo in the central server?  I know I can either clone or just copy the repo to the central server.  But the key is, without me having to clone that repo to my desktop again?  Its really big so that initial clone can take a long time.  Isn't there a way I can just edit a file to make my repo think its a clone instead of being the "parent"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information from where repository is cloned is written in `.hg/hgrc` file in your repository.

Create that file (if it does not exist) and add following lines

```
[paths]
default = https://my.parent.repository
```

Similary, if you want repository to think it is not clone of any repository, just remove those lines if they exist.

Comment: Yes it really is that easy, assuming the repos are identical.  Looks like you only have to copy the .hg dir.

Comment: I am doing that all the time. But I haven't tried to see what happens if repos are not identical.